# Cannot destructure property `auth` of 'undefined' or 'null'

Tags: node.js, adonis.js

I am trying to call the user's data from the controller, but I get the following error Can not destructure property `auth` of 'undefined' or 'null'.

```
async datosPersona({ auth }) {
    console.log(auth.username)
}

async datosPersona({ auth }) {
}
```

either of the two examples throws the same error

I'm using adonisjs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in the call.  Somewhere you are doing the equivalent of

```
 datosPersona(undefined)
```